# NOTES Alpha: Error copying file : open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, permissions, copy, backup

I need to create and restore a backup into my application. My backup logic is working well. but there was a problem for me that I describe below.

- I create my backup and restore it without uninstalling the application. its working well
- but when i create backup and uninstall the application, then i installing the application and try to restore it then i facing eorros.

My backup file location is `/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/APP_NAME/BACKUP_FOLDER/BACKUP_NAME.xml.` and i want to copy into `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/user/PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/BACKUP_NAME.xml`

and error is  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Downloads/APP_NAME/BACKUP_FOLDER/BACKUP_NAME.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: if you have stored your backup in local database then it will clear at the time of uninstalling the application

Comment: you are uploading your back up at cloud?

Comment: please upload manifest file

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling your app the backup files do not belong to your app anymore.

You could have checked that with File.exists() and File.canRead().

Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user select APP_NAME directory.

Or use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user choose individual files.

Comment: i've try this and i got `true` in file.canRead() and file.exists();

Comment: Hard to believe. Please post the relevant code in your post.

Comment: thankyou @blackapps but i found another way to fix my problem. lots of thankyou for help :)

Comment: @UrvishVocsy how to fix that issue ?